# How do you change Amazon SES access key for SMTP client / Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, amazon-web-services, smtp

I was trying to change my outbound SMTP password (after the LastPass breach). I set it up a while back using Amazon SES but now working with this sucker is anything but easy.

So I logged in to the Amazon SES console and generated a new access key. It then gave me the password for it:

[image]

But then when I enter both into Outlook:

[image]

it can't send any emails with a new key.

[image]

What am doing wrong?

PS. If I use the old key and password, Outlook can send emails just fine.

Comment: From [AWS article[(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-rotate-smtp-access-keys/): "Access keys that you create in the IAM console for an SMTP user work when customer is connecting to the SES API endpoint, but don't work with the Amazon SES SMTP interface. The keys generated in the IAM console are in a different format than the format required for the credentials required for Amazon SES SMTP servers." See the article for solutions.

Comment: In terms of Outlook client, maybe you could try to create a new profile (Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and re-configure your account to check if there're any differences.

Comment: This is incredible. I had to run [this Python script](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-rotate-smtp-access-keys/) to generate a password that I can use in Outlook. How would a "normal" person do this?